# Copy user selection from one canvas to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement a simple, select area on canvasA and then copy area to canvasB, I've got the selection part working but the drawing of the copied area doesn't want to work. The idea is that the user will select an area and then that selection will appear on another canvas when they finish the selection, i.e. say mousedown, drag rectangular area, mouseup (copy appears)

I confess I'm not much of a front end developer so fear I'm missing something obvious about how this stuff works as I'm just trying to knock something together to prove a concept and understand the basics at the moment.

JSFiddle is here - http://jsfiddle.net/bw4gw83a/2

HTML

```
<canvas id="original" width=300 height=300></canvas>
<canvas id="copybit" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Javascript

```
var original = document.getElementById("original");
var CTXoriginal = original.getContext("2d");
var copybit = document.getElementById("copybit");
var CTXcopybit = copybit.getContext("2d");


var background = new Image();
background.src = "https://i.imgur.com/F1pJYM1.jpg";

background.onload = function(){
    CTXoriginal.drawImage(background, 0, 0)
}

var imageData = CTXoriginal.getImageData(10, 10, 100, 100);
CTXcopybit.putImageData(imageData,0,0);
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Si

Comment: Your problem here is your `onload` handler is getting executed AFTER the `getImageData`. So when you call `getImageData`, the original canvas is actually blank at the time. Correcting this however will cause a cross-origin security error, which is a separate issue entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following guide might be helpful.

http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/graphics-and-imaging/2078-canvas-bitmap-operations-bitblt-in-javascript.html

It mentions you can draw a section of the image using

```
drawImage(image,sx,sy,sw,sh,dx,dy,dw,dh)
```

Where s is source, and d is destination.

From there you just have to determine the position of the click and drag to work out the co-ordinates and width/heights.

I've updated your fiddle just to demonstrate. It's very crude, so just click once somewhere in the top left of the image, then click again somewhere in the bottom right.

http://jsfiddle.net/treerock/1zpc8fz0/

Comment: That's great thanks, I'll see if I can work that into my existing code. Cheers